# Android AccessibilityNodeInfo.getTraversalAfter() returns null

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I am trying to use an accessibility service to determined the traversal order of elements on a screen. I am using onAccessibilityEvent to capture an AccessibilityNodeInfo, but no matter what node I find (the root, the event's source, etc.), nodeInfo.getTraversalAfter() and nodeInfo.getTraversalBefore() always return null. Is there something I'm missing with those calls?

Here is my onAccessibilityEvent method of my AccessibilityService class:

```
    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        AccessibilityNodeInfo eventNode = event.getSource();
        AccessibilityNodeInfo afterNode = eventNode.getTraversalAfter();
        AccessibilityNodeInfo beforeNode = eventNode.getTraversalBefore();
```

I haven't figured out an event or a node in the tree where beforeNode and afterNode are not both null.

I am currently registered to receive View Clicked accessiblity events in my service.xml:

```
    <accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
       android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
       android:canPerformGestures="true"
       android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
       android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeViewClicked"
    />
```